# How does IDA calculate stack variable offsets?

Tags: stack, reverse-engineering, ida

IDA is able to read the machine instructions of a subroutine and display the relative offsets of each variable that gets stored on the stack.

[image]

I'm writing a program that analyzes stack memory, and I would like to be able to put the values stored in the stack memory into their respective variable types. What logic is going on under the hood that enables IDA to display the stack variable offsets?

Thanks for your time.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It infers that from the function's code by looking on where and how stack addresses are used. Like, loading into a 4-byte register and doing arithmetics probably mean that stack memory from which the load was performed belongs to a some `int` variable.

If you want details on IDA's algorithm, I doubt you can found it. You can look at Avast's [Retargetable Decompiler](http://retdec.com/) open source project, that performs analysis much like IDA and study its code.

Comment: Ah. Okay, so it's a set of algorithms looking for things. Thanks! I wasn't sure if it was that, or another set of data held somewhere else. :)

Comment: I'd say it is a set of heuristics. That is, these algorithms is more of guessing than strict rules. On other hand, propagation of information uncovered by different heuristics from different places of the code greatly improves analysis accuracy.

Comment: Just to clarify, I was mainly asking how the stack variable offsets were generated. Rereading my question again made me realize that maybe you thought I was asking *only* about variable types? So yeah just want to double check, the stack variable *offsets* are also a set of IDA algorithms?

Comment: Figuring out variable type almost equals to finding out stack offset. If you know that a type is `int` then it means you can step off by `sizeof(int)` from the current SP and start over with next variable.

Comment: Right, yeah I get that. But if I don't know the type (and if I don't care either), then how would I even get the starting offsets for each variable? From your answer I took away that it's some IDA algorithms analyzing the machine code to guess **what** they are. Not necessarily **where** they are. But it is the same?

Comment: The value of SP register upon entering a function is a starting offset.

Comment: Of the whole stack frame, but finding the relative offsets for each variable in the function?

Comment: You look up `[SP]` operand within function's instructions and when finding something like `mov eax, [esp] ; add eax, 123` you make a guess that `ESP+0` is an `int` and the next starting offset is `ESP+4`.